# Combine iterations a loop as a single raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I am looking to combine all iterations of a loop into a single raster using R. I am performing shadow analysis where I perform the calculation for specific hours of a day and would like each calculation to be combined together into a single raster. For example when I have five hours to calculate I would like my raster to be: outRast = (i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5).

I am having trouble adding the iterations of the loop to a single raster where they will be combined, rather than it being over written.

Below is my code with the output iterations being saved out as a tif.

```
#Spring parametres
yy <- 2019
mm <- 03
dd <- 20
hh <- seq(10, 14)
```

```
#Shadow Analysis for spring season
for (i in hh) {
  jd <- JDymd(yy, mm, dd, i)
  sv <- sunvector(jd, rastCentre(ffLidar)[2], rastCentre(ffLidar)[1], -4)
  springShadows <- doshade(ffLidar, sv, 0.5)
  writeRaster(springShadows, paste("springShadows", i, ".tif"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing to combine the rasters in your code. Just create a raster for the first iteration, outside of the loop, and then sum them in each subsequent iteration within the loop. For your iterator in the for loop just remove the first element eg., `hh[-1]`. You can also make your code a bit more efficient by nesting functions, in this case into a single call.

```
springShadows <- doshade(ffLidar, sunvector(JDymd(yy, mm, dd, hh[1]),
                   rastCentre(ffLidar)[2], rastCentre(ffLidar)[1], -4), 0.5)
  for (i in hh[-1]) { 
    springShadows <- springShadows + doshade(ffLidar, 
                       sunvector(JDymd(yy, mm, dd, hh[i]),                 
                       rastCentre(ffLidar)[2], rastCentre(ffLidar)[1], -4), 0.5)
  }
writeRaster(springShadows, "springShadows".tif")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I agree that I am not doing anything to combine the rasters, hence my question, I am not sure where or what it should look like. Your example does not combine the rasters, it will write over the with the last iteration in the loop. I have tried: outRast[i] <- springShadows  But that does not provide the correct output.

Comment: Your exact request was `outRast = (i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5)` which is what this code is doing. It iteratively adds each new result to the previous result(s). If you want to retain each iterations result then you need to specify this. However, this code is the same as creating each raster and then summing them.